# Multiple thread without using Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm working on my lab lesson, Multithreading.

In multithreading I know that if we use `synchronized` keyword, it never let hit all the threads to method at the same time but put them in queue and let them access ony by one.

But My teacher said, its not a good practice to use synchronized (didnt get time to why, but will ask in next class).

Here is my code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Testmultithread {


    static String printMe(int inp) {

        return Integer.toString(inp);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> listofval = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        listofval.put("1", 1);
        listofval.put("2", 2);
        listofval.put("3", 3);
        listofval.put("4", 4);
        listofval.put("5", 5);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : listofval.entrySet()) {

            Testmultithread.printMe(entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

May I know please how can I achieve multithread in above code (Map entries accessing `printMe` method at multithread level) without using `synchronized` keyword... ?

Suggestion please...!

Thanks

Comment: Check out `java.util.concurrent.Lock` for one such mechanism you can use to synchronize your threads. See [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/how-to-use-locks-in-java-java-util-concurrent-locks-lock-tutorial-and-example/) for an example.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Locks? If so, do so, as the previous guy commented. However, if I were you I'd look into the differences and similarities of the different ways of handling multithreading, because many people will disagree with your professor saying that you should never use synchronized. Example post to read up on: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176762/is-it-time-to-deprecate-synchronized-wait-and-notify

Comment: @AustinSchäfer, Checking your link where its mentioned "thread[i] = new Thread(new PrintingJob(printerQueue), "Thread " + i);", May I know please how run() is being called in class PrintingJob ..?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking: do you mean why `PrintingJob` is able to have a `run()` method or why other classes are able to call `run()` for a `PrintingJob`? The `Thread` constructor being used here takes a `Runnable`, which `PrintingJob` implements, and a `String`, which becomes the thread name. Since `PrintingJob` implements `Runnable`, it has a `run()` method for other classes to call.

Comment: You only use synchronized to protect data, and to make sure changes are visible across threads. Your example doesn't really warrant the user of synchronized.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer, I mean to say we are creating a thread like this "new Thread(new PrintingJob(printerQueue), "Thread " + i)" and when we call thread[i].start();, does it calls automatically run() method implemented in PrintingJob class ...?

Comment: @Jon if we pass in a `Runnable` to the `Thread` constructor, then its `run()` method will be called (after the Thread's `run()` method is called) when we call `Thread.start()`. See [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--) for more information.

Comment: The code example you've provided doesn't show any use of threads. Without knowing how threads are going to be used in your program it's difficult to suggest an appropriate solution. (Personally, I don't understand what, "_Map entries accessing printMe method at multithread level_", actually means in terms of code)

Comment: There is no point in asking “how can I achieve multithread in above code … without using synchronized keyword”, as the synchronized keyword is not achieving multi-threading but rather *restricting* it. So decide what you are actually asking. Are you asking “how to achieve multi-threading” or are you asking “how to protect data from concurrent access without synchronized”. Besides, if your teacher says, it’s not a good practice to use synchronized, they should explain why. There’s nothing wrong with using synchronized in general.

Answer (score 0):

Have a method that just displays values from Nth index. 'N' would be static field level variable.

Have a Thread with 'run' method that runs forever and does the following.
1) Print value in index 'n'.
2) Increment N.
3) If N > list size, then 'break'.
Let 'N' be 'Atomic integer'.

In main method have two threads and just start them. Let your list have some 100 values in it so that you can see two threads picking values.

However, this is not thread safe and two threads can get same value of 'N'.

Good luck.